# Repeating a Rust task with tokio_timer

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm creating a repeating task in Rust using the Tokio framework. The following code is based on a [completed change request](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-timer/issues/6) to add this feature to the tokio-timer crate.

When trying to compile, I get the error message:

```
error[E0281]: type mismatch: the type `fn() {my_cron_func}` implements the trait `std::ops::FnMut<()>`, but the trait `std::ops::FnMut<((),)>` is required (expected tuple, found ())
  --> src/main.rs:19:36
   |
19 |     let background_tasks = wakeups.for_each(my_cron_func);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^

error[E0281]: type mismatch: the type `fn() {my_cron_func}` implements the trait `std::ops::FnOnce<()>`, but the trait `std::ops::FnOnce<((),)>` is required (expected tuple, found ())
  --> src/main.rs:19:36
   |
19 |     let background_tasks = wakeups.for_each(my_cron_func);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^

error[E0281]: type mismatch: the type `fn() {my_cron_func}` implements the trait `std::ops::FnMut<()>`, but the trait `std::ops::FnMut<((),)>` is required (expected tuple, found ())
  --> src/main.rs:20:10
   |
20 |     core.run(background_tasks).unwrap();
   |          ^^^
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `futures::stream::ForEach<tokio_timer::Interval, fn() {my_cron_func}, _>`

error[E0281]: type mismatch: the type `fn() {my_cron_func}` implements the trait `std::ops::FnOnce<()>`, but the trait `std::ops::FnOnce<((),)>` is required (expected tuple, found ())
  --> src/main.rs:20:10
   |
20 |     core.run(background_tasks).unwrap();
   |          ^^^
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `futures::stream::ForEach<tokio_timer::Interval, fn() {my_cron_func}, _>`
```

The error states that the return signature for the my_cron_func function is incorrect. What do I need to change/add to get the signature correct so it compiles?

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_timer;

use std::time::*;
use futures::*;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use tokio_timer::*;

pub fn main() {

    println!("The start");
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let timer = Timer::default();
    let duration = Duration::new(2, 0); // 2 seconds
    let wakeups = timer.interval(duration);

    // issues here
    let background_tasks = wakeups.for_each(my_cron_func);
    core.run(background_tasks).unwrap();

    println!("The end???");

}

fn my_cron_func() {
    println!("Repeating");
    Ok(());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what part of the error message is causing you trouble, but...

> type mismatch

You've provided the wrong type

> the type `fn() {my_cron_func}` implements the trait `std::ops::FnMut<()>`

When using `my_cron_func`, which is a function that takes no arguments

> but the trait `std::ops::FnMut<((),)>` is required

But a function that takes a single argument, the empty tuple, is required.

> (expected tuple, found ())

And the compiler tries to narrow down the problem.

If you review the documentation for the library you are using, specifically [`tokio_timer::Interval`](https://docs.rs/tokio-timer/0.1.0/tokio_timer/struct.Interval.html), you can see that it implements `futures::Stream` with the associated type `Item = ()`.

This changes the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): futures::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:36
   |
19 |     let background_tasks = wakeups.for_each(my_cron_func);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `()`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::IntoFuture` for `()`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): futures::Future` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:20:10
   |
20 |     core.run(background_tasks).unwrap();
   |          ^^^ the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `()`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::IntoFuture` for `()`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `futures::Future` for `futures::stream::ForEach<tokio_timer::Interval, fn(()) {my_cron_func}, ()>`
```

Reviewing the [documentation for `futures::Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.for_each), we can see that the closure passed to `for_each` needs to return a value that can be turned into a future that will yield `()`:

```
fn for_each<F, U>(self, f: F) -> ForEach<Self, F, U> 
    where F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> U,
          U: IntoFuture<Item=(), Error=Self::Error>,
          Self: Sized
```

Your function attempts to return something, except that there's no return type and you've used a `;` to end the function:

```
fn my_cron_func(a: ()) {
    println!("Repeating");
    Ok(());
}
```

[`futures::future::ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1/futures/future/fn.ok.html) does the trick:

```
fn my_cron_func(_: ()) -> futures::future::FutureResult<(), tokio_timer::TimerError> {
    println!("Repeating");
    futures::future::ok(())
}
```